# Diff file viewer?

Tags: version-control, diff

I'm looking for a tool that displays diff files (generated from mercurial, in my case) in some convinient manner. For example, the way bugzilla displays diff patches. Just to be clear, I'm not looking for something that compares/merges files, I already got the diff, just want a convinient way to inspect it.

I couldn't find anything that does that (diff syntax highlighters were the closest thing I got), anyone knows of anything?

Comment: Are you just trying to view a diff file, or do you want to apply the diff file to an original and see the changes in context?  You can't do the latter with just the diff file.

Comment: @Justin: As said, I don't need to apply/create diffs. Just to view an existing diff file in a more workable fashion.

Comment: In that case, what about a diff syntax highlighter is insufficient for you?

Comment: It's sufficient, just not optimal. Have you seen how bugzilla shows diffs? That's much more convinient.

Answer (score 0):

I really like Beyond Compare and Araxis Merge (especially Araxis).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried meld? (it works only in UNIX though..)

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the following Atlassian product 'FishEye' http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/

This allows you a lot of control over your version control system and code views/diffs/code reporting/visualisation etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question -- basically a good syntax highlighter for diff output.  I wanted something lightweight and free.

Now I'm using [sdif](https://github.com/kaz-utashiro/sdif) and [cdif](https://github.com/kaz-utashiro/cdif) together.

- `sdif` does the syntax highlighting you want
- `cdif` does word context diffs, so that on a modified line the words that have changed are highlighted differently

Answer (score -1):

As @tomahawk suggested, if you point FishEye at your Hg repository you'll be able to diff between revision of a file, and view a changeset as a diff.

If you want to look at arbitrary patch files, you could buy Atlassian's Crucible, which allows you to create a code review by uploading a patch, which you can then view as a nice diff (and comment on collaboratively, but that is probably not of interest to you). A 5 user Crucible licence costs $10.

(Disclosure: I'm a Crucible developer at Atlassian)